# Probability through sum of conditional probabilites

Tags: conditional-probability

I have a vector $x$ of random variables and a finite set of classes $C$. Also $x$ **has** to belong to one class. In the context of classification problems I have the transformation

$P(x) = P(x|c_1)P(c_1) + P(x|c_2)P(c_2) \ \cdots P(x|c_n)P(c_n)= \sum_{c \in C}P(x|c)P(c)$

Why is this equality true?

Thank you very much!

Comment: What is the exact meaning of $P(x)$? It will stand for a probability, but of wich event? If $x$ is a vector of random variables then it is not an event.

Comment: x is a vector of discrete random variables (which in my case have binary state). P(x) is the probability of the vector having its exact configuration (out of all possible finite configurations).

Answer (score 0):

In this answer $X$ stands for a random vector and $x$ is one of
the values that it can take. I am not sure whether this meets your
question (as my comment makes clear).

Maybe it will be of help anyhow. If not then let me know. In that
case I will delete it.

Formally $P\left(X=x\mid c_{i}\right)P\left(c_{i}\right)=P\left(X=x\wedge c_{i}\right)$
where $c_{i}$ stands for the event that $X$ belongs to class $i$.

Then $P\left(X=x\mid c_{1}\right)P\left(c_{1}\right)+\cdots+P\left(X=x\mid c_{n}\right)P\left(c_{n}\right)=P\left(X=x\wedge c_{1}\right)+\cdots+P\left(X=x\wedge c_{n}\right)$

Also $P\left(X=x\right)=P\left(\left[X=x\wedge c_{1}\right]\vee\cdots\vee\left[X=x\wedge c_{n}\right]\right)=P\left(X=x\wedge c_{1}\right)+\cdots+P\left(X=x\wedge c_{n}\right)$

This because $X$ must belong to exactly one class.

So LHS of first equality equals LHS of second equality.

Comment: thank you very much this is what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

It is due to the Law of Total Probability.

If the members of a set, $\{B_i\}$, are mutually exclusive and exhaustive events, then for any event $A$:

$$P(A) = \sum\limits_{B_i \in \{B_i\}} P(B_i)P(A\mid B_i)$$

Since each instance of $\vec X$ belongs to one and only one of the classes in $C$, we do have a set of mutually exclusive and exhaustive events.

$$\begin{align}\mathbb{\large P}(\vec X=\vec x) & = \mathbb{\large P}(\mathop{\large\cup}_{c\in C} (\vec X \in c\cap \vec X=\vec x)) \\ & = \sum\limits_{c \in C} \mathbb{\large P}(X\in c)\cdot \mathbb{\large P}( \vec X=\vec x \mid \vec X\in c) \\ & \color{grey}{= \mathbb{\large P}(\vec X\in c_1)\mathbb{\large P}(\vec X=\vec x\mid \vec X\in c_1)+\cdots+\mathbb{\large P}(\vec X\in c_n)\mathbb{\large P}(\vec X=\vec x\mid \vec X\in c_n) }\end{align}$$